# Array of ActiveRecord objects not allowing calls to the objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue calling objects within an array of ActiveRecord objects.

Here is my controller code building an array of things:

```
onething = Thing.where(this: id, that: id)
@things.push(onething) if onething.present?
```

This is looped in order to build an array of specific things with different ids passed inside the `where` method for this and that.

This and That being parents from thing:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :this
  belongs_to :that
end
```

Though in my view, when I call elements of the `@things` variable I get `undefined methods` errors.

When showing the `@things` variable in my view, in order to debug, I get things like this:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Thing id: 1 ....>]>, #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Thing id: 2.......>]>]
```

Whereas, a variable with records coming from a direct query such as `Thing.find(params[:id])` return something slightly different :

```
#<Thing id: 1, ....>
```

Why does the first one doesn't allow me to query the objects with simple queries such as `Thing.id` as the second works perfectly fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're pushing an `ActiveRecord::Relation` to the `@things` array (assuming that `@things` is indeed an array). So instead of ending up with an array of objects, you're winding up with an array consisting of arrays of objects. Use `concat` instead:

```
onething = Thing.where( this: id, that: id)
@things.concat(onething) if onething.present?
```

This will combine the two collections of objects into a single array.

Comment: Damn, spot on. Your solution does work. `@things` is indeed an array, i declared it as such before the loop: `@things = [] ` This was the only way I found to create this stack of objects. When I tried to add the `onething` result directly into the variable I got an error and had to declare `@things` first. Sole solution I found was to make it an array...

Comment: Do you see a better solution than the one we eventually came to above ? Or is it just the correct way to sequentally create a stack of active record objects ?

Comment: On last question: why do I not get an Active Record object when I assign the result of Model.find(something) into a variable ? (I mean I just get the object, without the ActiveRecord::relation text before it)

Comment: `find()` is designed to return a single ActiveRecord object. `where()` is designed to return _any_ matching records as an ActiveRecord::Relation. To see this in action, try these two different queries to see the difference in the SQL that's generated in the console – `Thing.where(id: [1,2,3])` vs. `Thing.find_by(id: [1,2,3]`. They'll produce the exact same SQL, with the exception that `find_by()` includes `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: To answer your other question, I'd need to see the rest of your code to see what you're doing. I'm more than happy to help, but we should probably do that outside of SO so we don't muddy up the comments. :-)

Comment: I can't really use find or find_by in my example so I guess my code is more or less OK. Though many thanks for the precision of the different type of data returned by Find and Where, didn't know that at all.

Comment: Not a problem. As far as your implementation goes, is there a reason why you're querying `Thing` one at a time and manually adding the objects to an array, instead of querying for all of the records you need in one query?